# Excel Round Average If

Tags: excel

How do I round the results of Average If to 2 decimals places? I've tried a number of methods and was unsuccessful. Thanks

```
=CONCATENATE("REQUIREMENT GUIDE - ",AVERAGEIF(Q11:Z11,"<>0")*3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this;

```
=CONCATENATE("REQUIREMENT GUIDE - ",ROUND(AVERAGEIF(Q11:Z11,"<>0")*3,2))
```

Comment: You can have this one.